# Understanding example of a quotient module over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I apologize for this basic question, just wish to check if my understanding/calculation is correct.

Let $\langle a\rangle$ denote the module (over $\mathbb{Z}_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$) generated by $a\in M$, where $M$ is some $\mathbb{Z}_5$-module.

(Suppose $a\neq 0$, $2a\neq 0$).

Then is it correct to say that $\langle a\rangle/\langle 2a\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

How I arrived at the conclusion is that $\langle a\rangle=\{a,2a,3a,4a,5a\}$, and then quotienting out by $\langle 2a\rangle$ reduces it to "$\{0,a\}$ with $a+a=0$".

Thanks.

Comment: No, since $\left<2a\right>=\left<a\right>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $5$ is a prime number, every $a\in \Bbb Z_5^*$ is a generator. Thus $\langle a\rangle=\langle 2a\rangle=\Bbb Z_5$ for every $a\neq0$. Then the quotient

$$\langle a \rangle / \langle 2a\rangle \cong \{0\}$$

Comment: You are welcome 